# How would i be able to change an int value?

Tags: java

I am writing a small program where the user has to guess a number. I want them to type in the number that they are guessing and then assign the value inserted by the player to the variable x to check if this is the right value. How could I get the inserted value and assign it to the x variable?

This is what I have so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner textIn = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Try to guess what number I am thinking of.");
    //X is the int I want to change
    int x = 100;

    //Z is the one I am comparing x to
    int z = 10;


    String zGuess = textIn.nextLine();
    boolean xTest = true;
    {
        if (x == z);
        System.out.println("You guessed right!");
    }
    //XTEST PART ONE   
    while (x < z) {
        System.out.println("X < Z");
        break;
    }
    //XTEST PART TWO   
    while (x > z) {
        System.out.println("X > Z");
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Uh, to change the value of an int variable you do `intVariable = someNewValue;`.

Comment: simply do this `x = textIn.nextInt();`

Comment: I strongly recommend reading a book or tutorial on Java programming. Learning the basics by asking questions is going to be slow and leave you with incomplete knowledge - you don't know what you need to ask.

Comment: Question should be improved. It is not clear enough what are you asking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple solution. Surround it in a while loop and always set `x = textIn.nextInt()`

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner textIn = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Try to guess what number I am thinking of.");
    //X is the int I want to change
    int x = -1;

    //Z is the one I am comparing x to
    int z = 10;

    while(x != z)
    {
        x = textIn.nextInt();
        if(x == z)
        {
            System.out.println("You got it right!");
        }

        else if(x < z)
        {
            System.out.println("Try a higher number.");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Try a lower number.");
        }

    }
    System.out.println("Great job!")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys.
@Patricia Shanahan- I am reading a book, I just decided that I wanted to do a little exploring on my own.

Answer (score 2):

The method you need is http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29

So in your case it means that

you can make `x = textIn.nextInt();`

Take a look at Scanner's javadoc
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html also.

And Oracle's tutorial how to use Scanner class

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/scanning.html

Comment: better suited for comment - or else put bit of more info

Comment: @sansix I extended my answer